# Can we run Access macro without MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created .mdb (Access macro) for client but problem is that they are migrating to Office365 so access will no be longer available for them.

Can I run Access macro without MS Access? I have googled it, I found .MDE file can solve the problem, but I don't have idea about it. Is there any alternative option or .MDE file will be the solution?

I'm a beginner in Access please let me know if any suggestions are available.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

But Access is indeed available through O365 - you just have to select and pay for the correct subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft just recently changed the Office 365 subscriptions. Microsoft Access is now included in **all** of the subscription levels except the *Business Essentials* subscription.

If users of your Access application have no license for Microsoft Access they still can use the [Microsoft Access Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040). The Access runtime is available for download free of charge and can run Access Database Applications, but you cannot make any design changes in it.